# vspace doesn't work properly

Tags: article, vspace

I am using `\vspace{3mm}` for separating the paragraphs in my article (`\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}`).
But most of the time it doesn't work properly. Sometimes it just puts the first few words/sentence of the following paragraph at the end of the previous one.

I need something like this:

```
Hello world.
\vspace{3mm}
How are you? I am good.
```

And sometimes I get this output:

```
 Hello world. How are you? 

 I am good.
```

Do you know why? Or do you know another command that does the same?

Comment: try separating the parts you wish to have vertical space with an empty line just after `\vspace` command... also a `\noindent` on the start of the next line could be needed

Comment: @koleygr if you fond yourself needing `\noindent` it is almost always a sign that the markup is wrong somewhere....

Comment: Mary if you want vertical space between paragraphs then you should set `\parskip` in the preamble, not add `\vspace` between each paragraph.

Comment: You are right... just tied to give more options because thought for the moment that the OP would not like to have indented the following text... Also, I use \noindent some times, but mostly inside some of my commands (of bold descriptions etc) and I don't think it is a mistake... Anyway... In your answer I would prefer the `\vspace` in the end of the first sentence and not in the beggining of the second just because I can read it easier (+1 by the way)

Comment: [Unchecked] You can use `Hello world\\[3mm] How are you`. However, I suggest you not to do that.

Comment: @JouleV ... I think you should prefer the word [Untested]

Comment: @koleygr but that would be wrong, the blank line should be before the vspace. Using vspace in horizontal mode is well defined but weird, you almost always want to avoid that.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle... Thanks, I use the way I described often, but it is always the last command of my paragraph. I can understand it is supposed to be considered as my `\vspace` command is still in horizontal mode, but in the case that is the last command, I think it will give the same result. Am I wrong?( Years ago, I used to place it just in its own "paragraph" between the paragraphs but for years now I am using it as a last command of a paragraph if this is necessary.) Follow-up: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/478991/is-a-vspace-placed-on-the-end-of-a-paragraph-a-bad-latex-coding

Comment: @koleygr it probably gives the same visual result but via a wildly different and more involved code path. If you use vspace in vmode it just directly adds the glue node to the current vertical list. If you use it in h mode then the vertical glue is added to a vadjust node in the current horizontal list which will, after linebreaking, migrate to the current vertical list and be re-inserted into the vertical list after the line that contained the vadjust node.

Answer (score 6):

You have

```
Hello world.
\vspace{3mm}
How are you? I am good.
```

Which is a single paragraph, so the `\vspace` is added after the current line, probably after `good.`

You could use

```
Hello world.

\vspace{3mm}
How are you? I am good.
```

Bur you should almost never need explicit spacing within the document anyway.